# Mongo DB Insert/Update of big amounts of data is slow (+20 Seconds)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to insert a lot of data as document into the database. It is usually +4k (pretty)-json rows / 150k characters. I'm inserting these all at once, but it still takes +20 seconds.

Is this a known limitation of mongodb? Are you aware of any settings or mongo forks that would provide a major performance boost? I can live with ~1 second.

- no indexes inside the document
- insert and update require the same amount of time
- default mongo configuration

Comment: Is it a single document that takes 150kb in json notation and inserting 1 such document takes 20 seconds?

Comment: Yes a single document.

Comment: how do you insert it? The shell buffer is limited to 4kb.

Comment: I'm using Meteor which is using the mongodb npm package. The data is sent as a single json document.

Comment: Meteor doesn't send binary, it stringifies it on the client, then parse it on the server, then converts it to bson, and only then mongo comes in play. You can enable profiler on the db side to confirm insert itself takes a tiny fraction of a second.

Comment: ohh, I'll check that out. Would you recommend to use a micro service to speed it up (e.g. small go app) or could I get good results by using the mongodb npm package directly?

Comment: You need to profile the whole stack. 20 secs is still too much. My point is it is unlikely the db is a bottleneck.